# Showing that e$^A$ is nonsingular for any diagonalizable matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Exactly what it says on the title. How do I show that *e* $^A$ is nonsingular for any diagonalizable matrix *A*?

I know that *e* $^A$ = X *e* $^D$X$^{-1}$

and

*A* = X*D*X$^{-1}$

where *A*, *X*, and *D* are all n x n matrices. Since *A* is diagonalizable, I don't need to use the definition of an exponential matrix. Where should I begin with proving that *e* $^A$ is nonsingular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fact that
$$\exp(A) = X \exp(D) X^{-1},$$
we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\det(\exp(A)) 
& = \det(X \exp(D) X^{-1}) \\
& = \det(X) \det(\exp(D)) \det(X^{-1}) \\
& = \det(X) \prod_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda_i} \det(X)^{-1} \\
& = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda_i} \\
& = e^{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i} \\
& = e^{\text{tr}(D)} \\
& \neq 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since $\exp(A)$ has a nonzero determinant, it is nonsingular.

Thanks to Thomas' reminder, we remark that $\text{tr}(D)$ is a complex-valued and $\det(\exp(A))$ is a nonzero complex number. In particular, if $\text{tr}(D)$ is real-valued, then we also see that $\det(\exp(A))$ is a positive real number.

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, then e$^A$ is nonsingular for any diagonalizable matrix A because its determinant is always going to be greater than 0?

Comment: Yes. More precisely we just need the determinant is nonzero. A square matrix is nonsingular if and only if its determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Yes, understood. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, it's non-singular even for complex diagonal matrices, where $>0$ is no longer true. If $D$ is diagonal, $e^D$ is diagonal with $e^{\lambda_i}$ on the diagonal, so the determinant is just $e^{\mathrm{tr} D}$ which is non-zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your reminder. I should modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this using your approach is to just see that if
$$A=XDX^{-1}$$
then letting
$$D=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\ 0 & \alpha_2 & 0 & \ldots \\ 0 & 0 & \alpha_3 & \ldots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{pmatrix}$$
we have
$$e^D=\begin{pmatrix}e^{\alpha_1} & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\ 0 & e^{\alpha_2} & 0 & \ldots \\ 0 & 0 & e^{\alpha_3} & \ldots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{pmatrix}$$
which isn't singular, hence neither is
$$e^A=Xe^DX^{-1}$$

Somewhat more directly would be to note that if $Av=\lambda v$ then $e^Av=e^{\lambda}v$ and, since the eigenvectors of a diagonalizable matrix must span the space and are also eigenvectors of $e^A$ with non-zero eigenvalues and span the space. Thus, there can be no eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$ as it would have to be linearly independent of the eigenvalues of $A$. The intuition here is that matrix exponentiation can basically just be applied to the eigenvalues.

Comment: nice formatting!